# Get source file path of a running python script from process id

Tags: python, linux

I have a process running in the background, a python one, with `ps -ef` I can see filename from running command : `UID PID PPID ... python ./filename.py`

How can I know where the file is located

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pwdx < PID > gives full directory the process is running from.

So, the full script would be

```
ps -ef | grep 'your process' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs pwdx
```

Though, you can simplify this into

```
pgrep 'your process' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs pwdx
```

Comment: Worth noting that this only works as long as the running python process doesn't do [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir), which updates the process' `cwd` attribute.